# R: adding a column to data frame according to field value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several factored fields:

```
data<-read.csv(text="ware,continent,val
snake,Europe,10
snake,America,15
snail,Europe,7
snail,America,12
mosquito,Europe,13
mosquito,America,5")
```

I need to add a column to the data, called, lets say, `max.val`, which will be the same for all entries sharing the same "ware" field. That is, I need to assign to entries with `ware` value `c("snake","snail","mosquito")` the values `c(25,22,18)` respectively. Final dataframe is

```
ware, continent, val, max.val
snake,Europe,10,25
snake,America,15,25
snail,Europe,7,22
...
```

I know that this can be solved using the construction:

```
library(dplyr)
data.2<-data %>% group_by(ware) %>% mutate(max.val=...) %>% ungroup()
```

How to arrange this assignment from the list `c(25,22,18)` according to factor value of the field `ware`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `c(25, 19, 18)`? (7 + 12 == 19)

Comment: I like `merge` for this: `key = data.frame(max.val = c(25, 22, 18), ware = c("snake", "snail", "mosquito"))`, then `merge(data, key)`. You can also use `match` or just a name vector - but those can be a little trickier with factors.